# Jupyter Notebook Kernel Not Connecting: Connection Failed (while Jupyter kernel connection works in Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook Kernel Not Connecting: Connection Failed:

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDrA0.png)

I have tried update ipykernel ipython and downgrade tornado, but all these methods didn't work for me.

I have installed Jupyter Notebook Extension in my Microsoft Visual Studio Code and it is weird that although kernel connection failed in the webpage-based Jupyter Notework, it still works well in VSC:

[VSC Jupyter Notebook Extension works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO6ya.png)

One of my coming final exams will use Jupyter Notebook, so the connection failure really troubles me presently. I would really appreciate it if someone could help identify what's going on here. I never changed my kernel and I didn't even understand how to set up different environments. Things just go wrong after I cheerfully `pip install tensorflow` though I think it is not package installation to blame.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you please post the error from your terminal output? That way we can look at the details of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks!!! I just solved the problem by completely uninstalled Anaconda with `Ananconda -clean --yes` and reinstalled it.

Comment: _FYI:_ Personally I think the problem arose because I had changed the directory of Jupyter Nb. Just after reinstallation, I try to change the working directory to the folder which is convenient for me. However after changing the directory, connection failure occurs again. Then I **set the Jupyter notebook working directory back to default**, connection works and everything go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, tried down-grading tornado, but that didn't work.

uninstalled jupyter and installed again and worked just fine

Comment: He mentions that he tried that in the OP & its didnt work